# Making sure a url parameter is not present, using regex

Tags: mysql, regex

I need 2 regular expressions that I will use in MySQL

- OK if one of the url parameters equals something (e.g page_id=5)
  I came up with this: `^https?:.*[?&]page_id=5([#&].*)?$`
- OK if a certain parameter is not present in the url (e.g do not match `[?&]page_id=`)
  **This is the one I need help with.**

This functionality is part of a bigger problem that does need to be implemented with regular expressions and they have to be compatible with MySQLs RLIKE

Answer (score 1):

your regexp looks fine - just use `NOT RLIKE`

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, it's a preset SQL template which I can no change, and I have to use RLIKE

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, MySQL's regex library does not support look-aheads, which is necessary for this kind of thing. As already stated, **NOT RLIKE** seems to be the only option.